# Реализация рандомно мерцающих элементов

Tags: jquery

```css
.elem {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
.elem.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <div class="elem" data-pos="1">1</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="2">2</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="3">3</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="4">4</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="5">5</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="6">6</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="7">7</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="8">8</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="9">9</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="10">10</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="11">11</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="12">12</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="13">13</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="14">14</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="15">15</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="16">16</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="17">17</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="18">18</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="19">19</div>
  <div class="elem" data-pos="20">20</div>
</div>
```

Нужно реализовать на jquery запуск рандомно мерцающих элементов.

Объясняю:
Запускаем функцию => рандомно добавляем/удаляем класс `active` одновременно у N (например 5) элементов, чтобы была некая анимация рандомно выбирающихся элементов, по итогу (через 10 секунд после запуска анимации) останавливаем анимацию и присваиваем класс `active` только элементам с аттрибутами `data-pos = 2,5,9`

Comment: Вы что-нибудь пробовали делать, чтобы заставить Ваши элементы "мирациать"?

Comment: Вы все-таки посмотрите в словаре, как пишется слово "мирацать", а то я Вам сейчас плюс поставлю за словотворчество.

Comment: Done! Извиняюсь, порой начинаю выдумывать новые слова.